# Django + South KeyError: 'ENGINE

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using Django 1.4 with latest south + 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'
I added south to installed_apps
syncdb returns this error:

```
ment/commands/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from south.management.commands.syncdb import Command as SyncCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 17, in <module>
    from south.db import dbs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.7.egg/south/db/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    if db_settings['ENGINE'] in engine_modules
KeyError: 'ENGINE'
```

this is taken from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1111',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB,character_set_connection=utf8,collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci'
    },
}
```

Do I need to add some variable to settings?

Comment: The problem was the option dic.
when I removed it syncdb worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the OPTIONS dict. That worked for me